# Python script command line input

Tags: python

To start i have little knowledge of python as i'm doing this assignment as a school project. I need to achieve the folowing:

create a script which i can start from `Windows` CMD and i need to add a parameter list to the first 3 files in a directory.

i start the script as follows:

```
c:\Python34\python.exe c:\Python34\directory.py c:\temp 3
```

content of the script:

```
##directory.py###
import os
import sys

dirs = os.listdir(sys.argv[1])
print (dirs)
```

The problem is i dont think the command line switch "3" is input in the script.

Any idea how i can achive this?

Comment: Do you understand what `sys.argv[1]` represents?

Comment: You want to display only `3` files as `3` is passed as an argument?

Comment: If sys.argv[1] gives you the the Directory C:\temp, what do you think incrementing the index may get you?
(sys.argv[2]) Give it a try, and after that please read the python tutorial! https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html (for Python 2.7) or https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html (for Python 3.3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't actually reference the second command-line variable.
Are you trying to list the first n files in a directory? If so then try

```
import os
import sys

dir_arg=sys.argv[1]
num_arg=int(sys.argv[2])  #need to convert second argument to a number

dirs=os.listdir(dir_arg)

print dirs[:num_arg]
```

Answer (score 0):

As other's have said sys.argv is simply a collection of command line arguments, so all you have to do is change your index in order to grab the appropriate values.